# How to connect my java program to neo4j localhost browser?

Tags: java, neo4j

Here is my code .Output is coming in console but it does not reflect in the browser.Please suggest me the solution.

```
`package connection;  
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;  
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;  
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;  
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;  
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;  
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;  
import java.io.File;  
public class Helloworld {  
        org.neo4j.graphdb.Node first ;
        org.neo4j.graphdb.Node second ;  
        static GraphDatabaseService gds ;  
        Relationship relation;  
        private static enum reltype implements RelationshipType {  
            KNOWS  
        }
```

> //for creating the database

```
void createdatabase(){   
            gds =new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(File_Path);  
            org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction trans = gds.beginTx();  
            first = gds.createNode();  
            first.setProperty("name","shashwat");  
            second = gds.createNode();  
            second.setProperty("name","shivansh");  
            relation = first.createRelationshipTo(second,reltype.KNOWS);  
            relation.setProperty("relation","friend");  
            trans.success();
```

> //For printing the success of updation

```
        System.out.println("succeded");    
        Iterable<Node> movies = gds.getAllNodes();  
        for(Node str : movies)
        {
          System.out.println(str.getProperty("name", "shashwat"));  
        }
    }
```

> // For shutting down

```
void shutdown(){  
            System.out.println("shutting in down");  
            gds.shutdown();  
            }  
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            Helloworld hw = new Helloworld();
            hw.createdatabase();
            hw.shutdown();
            }
    }  `
```

Comment: I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and then adding to your question. Giving some example code is typically a good start. Without that, it's difficult or impossible for people on the site to know what you've already tried, or guess as to what might be broken about your code.

Comment: Thank You sir, I am new on stackoverflow .

Comment: This is my code . I dont no how to add the code . So i am provideing code here ===

Comment: No problem at all. :) That's exactly why I wanted to point you toward some good resources, and help you figure out how to ask questions that will get you better answers.

Comment: I learned how to post a code . Please give me suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "does not reflect in the browser". Your code is running Neo4j embedded. Typically you do not connect with the browser to an embedded database. Are you looking for how to connect to a Neo4j running in server mode ? What is your question exactly ?

Comment: "I learned how to post a code . Please give me suggestions."  - What you (clearly) haven't done yet is how to ask a good / answerable question.  If you want people here to help you, you need to ask a clear / answerable question.  My suggestion: 1) read the link that Troy provided for you above, 2) understand it, 3) read Tom's comment, 4) improve your question.

Comment: My question is - when I run this program in eclipse, output shows in console but no changes occur in my localhost neo4j browser . For ex. No First Node and Second Node (as made in program) is formed in my localhost browser.

Answer (score 0):

the approach you are using is the "embedded" one, and while this code are running, the db which is in the "file_path" is occupied by the program, there for, you cannot launch the neo4j server with that db.
if you Finnish the program, you can then lunch the neo4j server and see the the nods on the browser.

i'm highly recommend that you read about neo4j "bolt driver" and "unmanaged extension"

Comment: After program compiled , the output comes on the console . Then i write ./bin/neo4j console command on ubuntu terminal, but still no changes occured. Please guide me for this query.